# Check usage or dependencies of SSL Certificate

Tags: apex, workflow, workflowoutboundmessage, ssl, sales-cloud

I am a newbie and came to know about SSL certificate is some tricky thing in in Salesforce. My salesforce certificate is to be expired in 15 days and i want to figure out the usage of the certificate. I don't even know how they work.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce is web based ERP system. SSL certificate will work similarly for Salesforce like other domains.

Usage of SSL Certificates: SSL Certs protect the data being exchanged between two clients (Web browser and Web Server). So third-party cannot intercept data communication over HTTPS.

Comment: Can we monitor the usage of Self Signed CA in salesforce only?

Comment: You should not use Self Signed certificate as browsers will throw warning message. SSL certificate from trusted CA will not cost much nowadays.